# Jquery + angularjs If statement working but href value not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ive run into a little problem and I can't seem figure out where ive went wrong. 
I am trying to change an href value outside of the select field when it changes. Console is logging properly but href is not changing.

**I would like the href value to change and contain text + an angularjs data like so "http://test.com/{{ch.names}}"

here is my select:

```
<select class="form-control3" name="ch" id="ch">
     <optgroup label="Ch">
                <option value="x6">x6</option>
                        <option value="P4">P4</option>
                </optgroup>
 </select>
```

this is the href attempting to change:

```
<a href="#" class="a-class">{{ch.names}}</a>
```

and here is my jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#ch").change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == 'P4') {
           $(".a-class").attr("href", "http://test.com/{{ch.names}}");
           console.log(".a-class");
        }
        else {
           $(".a-class").attr("href", "http://test2.com/{{ch.names}}");
           console.log(".a-class1");
        }
     });
  });
 </script>
```

when the values are changed it will log the class or class1 fitting the if statement but my href does not change where have I went wrong?

Comment: It is working for me but looks like {{ }} expression is what is causing this issue. are you using third part scripts like moustache.js or your own

Comment: @KrishnaDhungana im using angularjs as well and would like the end of the url to contain a value from the angular ng-repeat="ch in data"

Comment: This is a very non-Angular way of doing things.

Comment: @Nit can you suggest a better alternative please?

Comment: @Kepoly oh right. The problem is with dynamic angular content added. You have to use $compile to build expression before jquery changes the href.

Comment: @KrishnaDhungana do you have an example of how i could add $compile? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a lot cleaner to simply do this with Angular:

```
<div ng-app="TestApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestController">
        <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="option for option in options"></select>
        <a ng-href="http://test.com/{{selected}}">Selected: {{selected}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
var myApp = angular.module('TestApp',[]);

myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.options = ['x6', 'P4'];
    $scope.selected = 'P4';
}]);
```

Fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qk42jzxa/4/)

**EDIT**

From your comment, it sounds like you want to switch the whole URL to something else depending on the selection. You could save that data as a property in an array of objects, like this:

```
myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.options = [
        {
            title: 'x6',
            urlPrefix: 'http://test1.com/'
        }, {
            title: 'P4',
            urlPrefix: 'http://test2.com/'
        }];

    $scope.selected = $scope.options[1];
}]);
```

You'll need to change the HTML a little:

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="option.title for option in options"></select>
<a ng-href="{{selected.urlPrefix}}{{selected.title}}">Selected: {{selected.title}}</a>
```

Updated fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qk42jzxa/5/)

Comment: The correct usage would be to declare your controller as a module for your app: http://jsfiddle.net/aheLrk3v/

Comment: @Nit Ha, beat me to it. Updated. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @NateBarbettini I like this idea but what if the urls are different with each select option like http://{{change on select not to select value}}.com/{{change to option value}} that's why I had the if statement in my example

Comment: @Kepoly In that case, you should store the URL and option title in an object in the controller and bind an array of those objects to the `<select>`. I've updated my example; hopefully I understood what you are looking for.

Comment: No problem! FYI, the example was a little contrived: it would make more sense to just save the whole URL in an object on the scope, instead of rendering as `{{selected.urlPrefix}}{{selected.title}}`. Just do `{{selected.url}}` instead!

Comment: @NateBarbettini ok I will make sure I do this! I thought about a problem for the future with my database/php in the controller under scope.options can I add a value: 'XXX' a name: 'XX' and or id: 'XXXX' to the existing two options

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70181/discussion-between-kepoly-and-nate-barbettini).

Answer (score 0):

The angular way to do this is not to use jQuery at all. You create an app and a controller, bind the values and let angular take care of it. **[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8yx96RX8w1SeKmrnyjSX?p=preview)**

### Html:

```
<body ng-app="TestApp">
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <select class="form-control3" name="ch" id="ch" ng-model="href_value" ng-options="value.data group by value.group for value in opt_values"></select>
    <a href="{{href_value.url}}{{href_value.data}}" class="a-class">{{href_value.data}}</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

### Javascript:

```
angular.module('TestApp', [])
  .controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.opt_values = [
      {data: 'x6', url: "http://test.com/", group: "Ch"}, 
      {data: 'P4', url: "http://test2.com/", group: "Ch"}];
}]);
```